# Can't update the Walmart app on ONN tablet

Tags: applications

I have an ONN tablet that was sold by Walmart.  It comes with the Walmart app built in.  But whenever I try to run the Walmart app, it says I need to install an updated version.  But when I try to install the update,  it tells me that the new version is not suitable for my device.

As I understand it,  ONN is the house brand for Walmart.  So I would expect any updates to the Walmart app to be supported on any ONN tablet.

I've tried getting support from Walmart via their website,  but no luck.  Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: How old is the tablet (tablet may be just discontinued and hence no longer supported)? And the new app may require more RAM, or display resolution or whatever your tablet does not have.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my 10.1" ONN tablet.I couldn't even access the Walmart web sight through chrome because it will revert you back to the app. So what I did was go into settings/apps/Wamart. Then disable the Walmart app. On my tablet this eliminated the app symbol on my home page. Now I accessed the Walmart websight homepage through Chrome, bookmarked it and put it on my tablet hompage. Works great.

Comment: Didn't work for my 7 inch.  I still upvoted your answer.